# geoserver SLD in ol3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sld

i have some vector layers in geoserver with style (SLD)

When i add these layers though OL3 i want to use same SLD.

right now i am giving style to layer as below

```
style: new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                      color: '#f00',
                      width: 1
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
                    })
                  })
```

How can i get the same SLD which is present for the layer in geoserver and use in OL3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openlayers 3 does not yet have an SLD parser

There's an open issue at https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2954 that you may +1